# Error Code 2147500037 on Attempt for Bluetooth Connection in Windows Phone 8

Tags: comexception

I am attempting to establish an app-to-app bluetooth connection programmatically. Please see the following code snippet for the said purpose:

```
StreamSocket streamSocket = await PeerFinder.ConnectAsync(peerInformation);
```

I get this error whenever I try to do so:

```
An exception of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` occurred 
in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

ERROR CODE: 2147500037
```

Please advise on how to go around with this error.